# Getting Started with Windows

Tags: windows, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've tried to follow the tutorial but they are simply way to complicated.  Is there no .exe file simply download and install the program?  There is talk of cross-compiling (which I don't know what is), and a list of code I'm supposed to type somewhere.  Does anyone speak English, I mean plain English?

Thanks guys!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10848/getting-started-with-windows/) by [Hannibal](https://answers.ros.org/users/922/hannibal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LiMuBei](https://answers.ros.org/users/68/limubei/) on 2011-08-09**:
What exactly do you want to do? ROS support for windows is experimental currently at best. If you can summarize what you want to do with ROS you're gonna get better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do believe he's talking about the tutorials starting [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/win_ros/getting_started). And I suspect the exe he's talking about is the usual windows installer exe.

The current support is mostly there for linux developers who need to develop the odd simple program on windows (usually for monitoring, test purposes or debugging).

We're working on a more native implementation but it will never be as feature complete as  ros elsewhere.  If you only want to write simple programs, or algorithms with few dependencies, thats ok. But without a good software ecosystem (rosdeps/repositories/build environment), you'll never be able to build a complicated robot system very easily on windows.

Putting together complex systems is one of the biggest strengths of ros, and it loses that when it goes back to windows. Its hard converting (some of the windows devs Ive brought across to linux usually take at least six months to really reinvent their thinking), but the benefits are worth it.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2011-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What tutorial are you referring to? There are actually a lot of tutorials regarding different things. Windows support is still starting to develop.

There is no .exe, ROS is not just one program, but a large collection of programs that solve different purposes. You should probably read the introductionary tutorials at ros.org to grasp the concepts.

If you have some concrete question, ask that. You will find answers in English here.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1